# Distributions with exactly $n$ moments

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For a sufficiently rich space probability space we know that
$$L^1 \supsetneq L^2 \supsetneq L^3 \supsetneq \dotsb \supsetneq L^\infty.$$
Nevertheless, all interesting distributions I know have either no finite moments (e.g. Cauchy distribution), one finite moment (e.g. student-t distribution with 2 degrees of freedom) or all finite moments (e.g. normal distribution). Are there any interesting/often-used distributions with exactly $n$ finite moments for $n>2$, e.g. for $n=7$?

Comment: @404. I'm relatively new here, so I am amazed and intrigued with something. How are you a bot if you have math questions in your profile? Are we that advanced in AI already? Or did you mean a bot uses your account ocasionaly to warn users?

Comment: Yes. The whole class of Pareto (fat-tailed) distributions: $P(X_\alpha>t)=t^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0$. They have finite $\lceil\alpha\rceil-1$ moments.

Comment: @A.S.: That comment looks like an answer to me.